# SCP results look strange when using >> to append to file

Tags: bash, shell-script, scp, tail

I am trying to record a reoccurring test to a txt file using *tail* but there is an issue with the output.

The commands I am running are:

```
script -q /dev/stdout -c 'scp /home/user/test.img user@pc28:/tmp' | tee /home/user/scp.log
```

```
tail -3 /home/user/scp.log >> /home/user/test.txt
```

The issue is the text looks like--

```
^Mtest.img                                                                                                                                                                           
0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^Mtest.img                                                                                                                                                                          
16%   82MB  81.7MB/s   00:05 ETA^Mtest.img                                                                                                                                                                          
35%  178MB  83.2MB/s   00:03 ETA^Mtest.img                                                                                                                                                                          
51%  256MB  82.7MB/s   00:02 ETA^Mtest.img                                                                                                                                                             
65%  328MB  81.6MB/s   00:02 ETA^Mtest.img                                                                                                                                                                          
84%  421MB  82.8MB/s   00:00 ETA^Mtest.img                                                                                                                                                         
100%  500MB  87.0MB/s   00:05`
```

instead of

```
*test.img 
100%  500MB  87.0MB/s   00:05*
```

which is what it looks like if i *cat* the file.
I see the long messy output if i *less* or *vi* the file.

Comment: This is because you are looking at the standard error output, the progress reports which all end with `\r` instead of `\n`. What output do you actually want? What are you expecting here?

Comment: Why are you using `script` at all here?

Comment: @roaima my goal is to run scp from a bash script and i can't record the progress/speed unless i use script

Comment: @terdon I want my output to ideally just show the 100% line instead of each step of progress (0% 16% 35% etc)

Comment: "_i can't record the progress/speed unless i use script_" if it's a noninteractive script there's no point recording progress. Just capture the speed and duration

Comment: @roaima i think i remember if i just use 'scp /home/user/test.img user@pc28:/tmp >> /home/user/scp.log' from a bash script the speed and duration do not show. I can't say 100% until i go back to work.